# How to use Flink Metrics

Tags: java, apache-flink, metrics

I have an Apache Flink cluster with the standalone mode, I want to config Flink Metrics.

#### config in flink-conf.yaml

```
metrics.reporters: my_jmx_reporter,my_other_reporter

metrics.reporter.my_jmx_reporter.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.jmx.JMXReporter
metrics.reporter.my_jmx_reporter.port: 9020-9040

metrics.reporter.my_other_reporter.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporter
metrics.reporter.my_other_reporter.host: 10.0.0.203
metrics.reporter.my_other_reporter.port: 10000
```

#### exception

```java
2019-01-17 20:54:25.758 [Flink-MetricRegistry-thread-1] WARN  com.codahale.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporter  - Unable to report to Graphite
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:277)
        at com.codahale.metrics.graphite.Graphite.connect(Graphite.java:128)
        at com.codahale.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporter.report(GraphiteReporter.java:166)
        at org.apache.flink.dropwizard.ScheduledDropwizardReporter.report(ScheduledDropwizardReporter.java:231)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl$ReporterTask.run(MetricRegistryImpl.java:427)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

#### what do I need to do

use a program listen 10000 port on 10.0.0.203 or other something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are reporting to host `10.0.0.203:10000`, so you need a program listening port `10000` on `10.0.0.203`. Otherwise flink is unable to send message to it. In this case, you need to start [`Graphite`](https://graphiteapp.org/) on this host. See the [doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/metrics.html).

Answer (score 0):

Which service does your company use as the metric service？Then you should implement flink metric reporter to report that service。
For example open falcon, opentsdb and so on.